# is Opera VPN (sites blocking Tor exit nodes) recommended?

Tags: vpn, web-browser

There are anonyous images boards blocking write operations from Tor exit nodes.

In such cases I use Opera VPN.

[image]

How private and secure is Opera VPN? Better than real IP address? I wonder why this service is for free? How they make profit?

Comment: This question is explicitly not about Tor.

Comment: In some "free VPN" situations (Hola) your traffic is typically routed through another user's computer. Every user in the network functions as an exit node; there's no additional cost to anyone. In Opera's case, they monitor your traffic and sell it to China.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opera's free VPN offering is not really to be considered private because Opera is now owned by a Chinese consortium of unknown reputation. Remember that China is an undemocratic regime that censors its own Internet. I use it sometimes for viewing videos "not available in your country".

Also remember that Opera is now just another Google Chrome clone and not a true open source (FOSS) browser like Firefox. Ideally you use Firefox and a VPN that is really trustworthy. You can find some here: https://thebestvpn.com/

Usually when a service is free you pay with your data. There is a famous saying - "when it's free you are the product" - for such cases. This of course applies only for corporate tools and services. Real open source can be free because contributors get hired as experts.

Comment: I think both OP and you are too unspecific. OP: Recommended by whom? You: Just because there are some bad smells this does not imply it really is shady. You're just suspecting it may be and like being on the safe side. Side note: You will always need to decide if you trust a VPN based on incomplete information if you are not the server admin yourself and having the server in your own data center.